# Athena permission denied while executing a query

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, amazon-athena

I have an AWS Lambda function that runs an Athena query to read some data.

Here is the policy:

```json
    {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Sid": "Sid0",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": [
                    "athena:GetQueryExecution",
                    "athena:GetQueryResults",
                    "athena:GetWorkGroup",
                    "athena:StartQueryExecution",
                    "athena:StopQueryExecution"
                ],
                "Resource": "*"
            },
            {
                "Sid": "Sid2",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": [
                    "glue:GetTable"
                ],
                "Resource": "*"
            },
            {
                "Sid": "Sid4",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": [
                    "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
                    "s3:GetObject",
                    "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
                    "s3:PutObject"
                ],
                "Resource": [
                    "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET/db-access/*"
                ]
            },
            {
                "Sid": "Sid5",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": [
                    "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
                    "s3:ListBucket",
                    "s3:GetBucketLocation"
                ],
                "Resource": [
                    "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

When I run the query with admin user it works. When I run it with the Lambda role/policy it fails.

```json
    "StatementType": "DML",
    "ResultConfiguration": {
        "OutputLocation": "s3://BUCKET/db-access/athena-query-results/e26d9574-503c-45d8-9730-3d39e4293b3f.csv"
    },
    "QueryExecutionContext": {},
    "Status": {
        "State": "FAILED",
        "StateChangeReason": "Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: 09DF293291383C76; S3 Extended Request ID: qx5MpYNSpoqWQHdQVT7rqExhkxaNI3oFlD4tXmPwwUtHNAw3wrd9cjrdeYb3mGA8X1Lnql+RSyA=; Proxy: null)",
        "SubmissionDateTime": "2020-10-20T12:17:34.855000+02:00",
        "CompletionDateTime": "2020-10-20T12:17:50.086000+02:00"
    },
```

One really annoying aspect of this that we have cloudtrail enabled for the account but there is not such a requestid (09DF293291383C76 for example) when we query Cloudtrail. It seems that Athena is unable to write the result to the location even though with the same policy I am able to PutObject to that location. Not sure what else Athena is running before the PutObject but that is the action that is missing from the action list. Not sure how to debug this further.

Update:

After some investigation and help from AWS we tracked down the issue being a missing read permission from the Athena table's S3 location. Unfortunately we missed that location with CloudTrail too and Athena's error messages does not let you determine what is the actual problem.

Comment: What about KMS? If you objects are encrypted with KMS, lambda execution role will require permissions to KMS as well.

Comment: Would it produce an S3 error though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you writing your results to the same place where the table's data is stored? Otherwise there's your problem.

It could also be `s3:PutObjectAcl` that's missing, but IIRC Athena doesn't need it.

There's a lot that is unclear with your question, we can't possibly debug this without knowing much more about your environment. You say you think it's writing the results that is the problem, but what makes you say that?

S3 doesn't log object level operations in CloudTrail by default, but you can enable that, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/logging-data-events-with-cloudtrail.html

Comment: Thanks Theo. The problem was unclear because we had a setup where Athena was not able to read the source S3 where the table data is. Athena does not provide a log where it says: "I cannot read this location" and we initially missed the source bucket with CloudTrail.

Comment: Yes we should have enabled logging everything for S3 and not picking individual buckets, the initial run with CloudTrail was too overwhelming and we could not find anything in the data so we went for a narrow trail that excluded the real problem.

Comment: S3 doesn't expose information about the object for security reasons, IIRC, but you'd think that Athena could be more helpful since it knows which object failed, and it has more information about the security context.

Comment: Exactly. We use this to create a CloudTrail trail that captures all data events (excluding the management events) and crate an Athena table so that we can query the S3 ID that we get from the error. Maybe this will help us next time to sort this out faster.

Comment: That could be an expensive solution if you leave it on always. Athena generates a lot of S3 operations and CloudTrail data events are more than twice as expensive as the S3 operations themselves (an S3 `GET` costs $0.4 per million, CloudTrail charges $1 per million operations).